# App Engine SDK suppress request logging

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

Using the GAE Python SDK on Linux and would like to turn down the "noise" created by each request for JS, CSS and image assets.

Is there a parameter passable when running the SDK to reduce default request logging or can this be adjusted in the app config somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

However, you can download all the logs via the logs API and have a script to parse it.  Here's an example:

http://google-app-engine-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/logparser/logparser.py