# Google app engine disable request logging

Tags: django, google-app-engine, logging

I'm looking for a way to filter out request logging spam so I can more easily see warnings or errors.

This seems to work locally:

```
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'WARNING',
    }
}
```

but fails on GAE

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600998/app-engine-sdk-suppress-request-logging) this isn't possible and I need to use a log parser instead. However, that was 7 years ago, so I'm wondering if there's now a way to get this to work. Additionally, the answer links to a log parser which results in a 404, so if this isn't possible, I would like a link to a working log parser

Comment: The same applies at this time. In fact those requests are handled by the NGINX on the top of your app rather than in the app itself so it is not possible to disable them since you cannot manage that NGINX

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the logging sink.

1. In Google Cloud go to Logging > Logs Router
2. Edit the `default` bucket
3. Under "choose log to include in sink" add the logname you want to exclude.
4. To test your config click "PREVIEW LOGS" and review your setting before saving.

Here you can add any log queries to adjust your logging.

[image]

---

Official Doc: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2